# Which linux distro is optimal to use Android Studio with no hiccups?

Tags: android, linux, linux-distribution, android-emulator

I have been using windows and I have ran into trouble a lot. First there were problems with maps API, now my emulator started slowing down. Its really frustrating. I searched the web and I keep hearing that Ubuntu is good. Is this good? Which is my best option?

Comment: it's too broad. If you don't have enough resource then there'll be hiccups at some point, regardless of any distro you use. That said nowadays [the fastest distro nowadays in most benchmarks is Intel's Clear Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/52815/3579)

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try that out.

Comment: Oops turns out mt PC is not compatible. I have Legacy BIOS. It requires UEFI

Comment: Clear Linux just requires [SSE 4.2, AES-NI and PCLMUL](https://docs.01.org/clearlinux/latest/reference/system-requirements.html). If there's no UEFI then a [software UEFI like DUET](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/index.html) can be used without problem. But if your PC has no UEFI then it's already too old and probably not suitable for modern development. Running the virtual machine and IDE needs a lot of CPU and memory resources

Comment: Its a bit old but it has 8gb of ram and an i5 processor 2nd gen though. I'am planning to upgrade soon.